# Using bootstrap sizing based on containing div size?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

**Scenario**

Let's say I have two divs, side by side.

- div1: 500px wide
- div2: taking up the remaining width

I want the items in div2 to be responsive using bootstrap so that I can leverage `xs, sm, lg, xl` respectively eg `mt-sm-3` which specifies the margin top ONLY for the small sizes.

Furthermore, I don't want the bootstrap sizing to trigger based on browser window width but instead the width of the containing parent div.

**Question**

Is this possible with bootstrap? If so, how?

**Thoughts**

1. Spoofing classes for div2 eg. have javascript attach, as classnames, `custom-[xs,sm,lg,xl]` depending on the size. This would be a ridiculous amount of busy work and kind of defeats the purpose of using such a widely adopted css library.
2. Put an iframe inside of the div which has bootstrap loaded into it. I don't necessarily like this one because I'm working with a react/redux project and it becomes a bit of a nuisance to pull this off.

Comment: This won't work with native bootstrap, because, as you may have guessed, BS uses media queries to determine the width of the `xs, sm, lg, xl` classes - which is based on browser width. You should probably skip bootstrap and use something custom.

Comment: @disinfor it's definitely window width, not browser width. That said, I agree with you that path of least resistance is going to be with something custom; to my misfortune.

Comment: I meant window width! Whoops! But, yeah, still custom. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing my own solution. It works by checking target div size every 100ms then attaches a size to it: xs, sm, md, lg, xl and will work with custom sizing metrics. I put a couple examples in my basic index.html

https://github.com/jacksonkr/substrap/tree/dev

Answer (score 1):

Try the below structure

```
<div class="d-flex">
    <div style="width:500px;"></div>
    <div class="w-100"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can also add `flex-grow-1` instead of `w-100`.

Comment: OP had a specific requirement for top margin at smaller parent container widths:  _"respectively e.g. `mt-sm-3` which specifies the margin top ONLY for the small sizes"_ This answer won't satisfy that requirement.